# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.SelectNamesDialog get Email Group

Tags: outlook, mapi

Currently I'm using Outlook `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.SelectNamesDialog` to get **Contacts**, But in the **Address Book** (`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.SelectNamesDialog`) there are **group emails** also.

I'm looking for a way to get all the emails in that email group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example on how to retrieve members from an **Exchange Distribution List** via [`SelectNamesDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147595.aspx) selection.

```cs
Outlook.SelectNamesDialog names =  Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetSelectNamesDialog();
names.SetDefaultDisplayMode(Outlook.OlDefaultSelectNamesDisplayMode.olDefaultMembers);
names.ForceResolution = true;
names.Caption = "Please selection something";
if (names.Display())
{
    Outlook.Recipients recipients = names.Recipients;
    foreach (Outlook.Recipient recipient in recipients)
    {
        Outlook.AddressEntry entry = recipient.AddressEntry;
        if (entry.AddressEntryUserType == Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeDistributionListAddressEntry)
        {
            Outlook.ExchangeDistributionList list = entry.GetExchangeDistributionList();
            Outlook.AddressEntries members = list.GetExchangeDistributionListMembers();
            foreach (Outlook.AddressEntry member in members)
            {
                Outlook.ExchangeUser user = member.GetExchangeUser();
                string address = user.PrimarySmtpAddress;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have the addresses, it would be easily to add them to a collection.

Comment: That's the exact solution, working great. Thank you for the help silverNinja cheers

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer will fail for the distribution lists from your Contacts folder.
All you need to do is access Recipient.AddressEntry.Members collection (be prepared to handle nulls).

Comment: currently what I'm doing is get the recipiets list from Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.SelectNamesDialog as return type and loop through each recipient to access each once property. But Recipient object doesn't contain .AddressEntry.Members. Can you clarify this pls :)

Comment: Recipient object in OOM does contain the AddressEntry property. And the AddressEntry object contain the Members property.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dmitry. I got the complete solution as SliverNinja mentioned. cheers :)